# Showing a badge count in android

Tags: android

**What I currently have:**

1. I Have a sample application where I need to display the badge count
   for the android
2. I am using the library
   https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

**What is happening:**
Badge count is not getting displayed

**I tried in devices:**

1. Samsung-M20 --- With Android Version-9
2. RealMe2-Pro --- With Android Version-9

**CODE:**

```
package com.androidstt.badgetest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        int badgeCount = 22;
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, badgeCount); //for 1.1.4+


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken Internet Permission?

Comment: @PratikButani ...   Why i need internet permission ... Because in code i am hard-coding count to 22 in the code i have posted

Comment: Take permission and check.

Comment: @PratikButani ... Tried ...still not displaying

Comment: Okay, I told you as defined [here](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/337#issuecomment-531627010)

Comment: You can create [issue](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/new) here.